# Image rendering issue in iPad Safari and PC browsers

Tags: html, ios, css

Issue : 
PC browsers -- expected
[image]

iPad rendering
[image]

Description: 
The above image is the expected result in all PC and Android browsers, but in iPad, it renders in a wrong result as second image. 
Here is the codes below, I found if I take off width and height in .close-btn, the image size would be same as expected one except button size is still not correct.
What if I replace button as div, it is in the correct result.
What does iPad do for the button element?
 
What if I want to keep using button for clearly semantics tag, how can I modify it for iPad?

```
/** HTML */
    <button class="close-btn">
         <img src="close-btn.png" />
    </button>

/** CSS */
    .close-btn {
      position: absolute;
      right: 20px;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      img{
        width: 23.5px;
        height: 23.5px;
      }
    }
```

Comment: My first guess would be, that there’s probably some default padding that gets applied to the button by the user agent stylesheet on iPads.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this to your `.close-btn`

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

becouse iPad changes the look of buttons and other controls to resemble standard controls.